# Dart Map : get the first key only

Tags: dart

```
void main() { 
   var details = {'LastName':'Martin','FirstName':'Pierre'}; 
   print(details.keys); 
}
```

It will produce the following output : (LastName, FirstName)

But How can I print "LastName" only ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
print(details.keys.toList().first);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of calling method `toList`?

Comment: There are two ways to get the first element for any `List` object by using: `first` method or through indexes, in this case, it'd be `[0]`, but if you need the third element then it'd be `[2]` and so on. An `Iterable` object can use `first` method only.

Comment: ... and `details.keys` is an iterable, so `details.keys.first` is sufficient. No need for calling `toList()`.

Answer (score 7):

As defined in [dart docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Map/keys.html) the method `Map.keys` returns an `Iterable` object, that is in iteself an iterable (List) like object. You can access the first element of an iterable with the `first` getter method. And you can use `last` to access the last element of an `Iterable`

```dart
void main() { 
   var details = {'LastName':'Martin','FirstName':'Pierre'}; 
   print(details.keys.first);  //LastName
   print(details.keys.last);  //FirstName
}
```